# What user id does an android license verification response contain?

Tags: java, android, security

I'm using the [Android License Verification Library](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html)

Could someone tell me what does the returned user id field hold?

It looks like a hash or a base64 encoded something, but I couldn't figure out what it really is...

I'm checking the license on the server side and I need to be able to identify the user based on that userid field. I need a way to connect the response to a google account.

Comment: did you find an answer?

Comment: 5 years after this was posted, I have the same question, and I still cannot find any documentation that describes the user id field.  It seems to be an application-specific hash because it does not decode as a plain base64 string.  It's probably a hash of the app package, user name, etc, but still it would be nice to have official word about it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `user id` is obfuscated for user privacy by Google as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14423161/19633950) answer

Also this `user id` is application spesific as described in source code of LVL [ResponseData](https://github.com/google/play-licensing/blob/master/lvl_library/src/main/java/com/google/android/vending/licensing/ResponseData.java).

```
// Application-specific user identifier.
data.userId = fields[4];
```

Which means its different for every app even if the user is same.

What you can do is generate a nonce based on user id and request a license with that nonce and reject the request if the nonce is not same as suggested on offical [Google Licensing Server-Side License Verification](https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/server-side-verification#generate-nonce) documentation.

> **Generate a suitable nonce value**
>
> Use one of the following techniques to
> create a nonce value that's difficult to guess:
>
> - Generate a hash value based on the user's ID.
> - Generate a random valueon a per-user basis. Store this random value on your app's server as
>   part of a given user's attributes.