# Mapping users from Google Checkout to Android Licensing responses

Tags: android

I am using Android Licensing as described here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/market/licensing/index.html

(...to verify that my customers for my android app have actually payed for the app.) My app has a server component on the web, and for extra safety I'm doing the license validation on this server.

It all works okay. Now, to my problem. Since each new user ties up resources on my central server, I'm actually kind of reluctant to have non-paying users. I have seen some evidence of users continuing to use the app after having gotten a refund (per the normal 15-minute grace period).

To curb this behavior, it would be great if there was some way to map the payment of users at Google Checkout, to actual users in my system. Is this possible?

The ResponseData that I receive from the android license server contains a field called "userId", but this doesn't seem to correspond to any information in Google Checkout. (See http://www.androidadb.com/source/skylight1-read-only/GoogleLVL/src/com/android/vending/licensing/ResponseData.java.html for the definition of ResponseData.)

Is it possible to determine which payment in Checkout maps to which app installation?

Comment: I can't believe this question has been voted for two times and received no answer in the last nine months. Although this might explain a lot... Either way, can you tell us how you find out that users continue to use your app after having gotten a refund? Through other data than the iserId? And shouldn't the Google Play licensing information reflect the fact that a user got a refund?

Comment: The reason I know/suspect my service has been used by non-paying users is that I have seen in my server logs that users have registered as new users, and then used my service for 45 minutes, on a day where I actually made no sales at all (my app isn't all that popular :-) ). It is no big problem, but I was surprised that the obvious fix of letting the server check that users have payed isn't possible.

Comment: Looking at the userId field, I found out this is Base64 encrypted, and revsering it provides a string like this B@XXXXXXXX, where the X...X is a 8 hex digits number, like an address of some sort!?
Anyone to comment on this, could this help us identify users?

Comment: I know for a fact now that if we cancel a particular order beyond the first day, some user actually get the app for free! Just confirmed from Google today, who mentioned to avoid cancelling any orders past the 15 minutes delay!

Comment: Same problem here. Ever since Google is no longer revealing customer e-mails, it's been a support minefield.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I currently understand it, the `userId` is obfuscated even on a per-app basis such that you can uniquely identify users per app but not figure which user it is nor whether the same user bought another app.

But I'm not sure you really need to identify these customers based on `userId`. If you have a server running anyway, the best way to protect your app is to have your server check the licence.

1. App -> Server: Give me a new nonce
2. Server -> App: Here is a secure random nonce
3. App -> Licence Service: Check user licence with this secure random nonce
4. Licence Service -> App: Signed licence response including repetition of nonce
5. App -> Server: Check licence signature with secret key (only on server)
6. Server -> App: Reject, or provide random token for access, etc

In this scenario, you won't authenticate users even if they mess with your LVL checking code.

However, you may of course introduce vulnerabilities after step 6 if you don't watch your step. Still, if you're  currently using the standard LVL code and App-side licence check with the secret key stored in your app, changing to a mechanism as sketched above would be a *huge* improvement (there's even  a script to remove standard LVL checking code from apps).