# Getting google username from userid

Tags: android, oauth, gmail

I use [Android market api](http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/)
in order to fetch information from google playstore. The api returns a user id corresponding to each reviewer for an application. Sample user id's returned by the api would look like this:

```
cid-lg:AOqpTOGMFCTbFodkU6yTr_DttkugfrgfI0-q6a008jeD67cKE1xoDv_bT8gjjILcPcxOOZ0m3atfEDl9O0RLiYM
cid-gp:AOqpTOGCrH6yXqvnrDmTZ6C1gJrLBYioEemkZq4nflx-e1c7Eg6coh1c8q_mhtJB07-fUBps0a-AxTHMBLuDOGA
cid-gp:AOqpTOHUIW7EByEinUUKXzZeHRKC3UvbAXnGtuaVE2i4rIUXMw-zfD3WsXr4Hl25fCPSKx4ix6GXT-gt9NM_9P0
```

These are the user id's for 3 different reviewers for a single application.

Is there a way out by which I can get the google username corresponding to these user id's ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/9718947/1856738 and also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/14578627/1856738

Comment: Though I have checked SO before posting this, I have not seen those links which you mentioned. Also, I do not understand clearly what is being discussed there and I am not able to co-relate it with my current issue. Any possible solutions , comments is much appreciated

Comment: "Users from Google Checkout" are "Google Usernames", hence, effectively, http://stackoverflow.com/q/9718947/1856738 is the same question as yours. The answer is, there is no known mapping.